# Static constructor and sharing data

Tags: c#

I need to share an instance of an object between two static objects as described beneath. The first time I call the property `MyProperty` I must instantiate `MyObject`.

As a clever reader, you've found the bug. The first time I'll use the `First`, I'll instantiate `MyProperty` and the first time I'll use `Second`, I'll instantiate `MyProperty`. That's reinitialise it and loose all the state of this object.

```
public static class First
{
    static First() { MyProperty = new MyObject(); }
    public static MyProperty{ get; set; }
}

public static class Second
{
    static Second() { MyProperty = new MyObject(); }
    public static MyProperty
    {
        get { return First.MyProperty; }
        set { First.MyProperty= value; }
    }
}
```

The solution in this case is just to check nullity:

```
static Second()
{
    if(MyProperty == null) MyProperty = new MyObject();
}
```

But, for me there's a smell. I've got the feeling of bad code. So there's my question: is there a pattern or some good advices to share a context between two static objects?

Comment: why are you using `static`? it creates messes like this.

Comment: Because it is a shared context between different parts of the application.

Comment: "Smell" doesn't quite cover it :) Without the background of what behaviour you require (for which `static` is your current solution) it's tricky to get at a good answer. Why do First and Second both need to be static, and why do they need to refer to the same reference of an instance type?

Comment: if you have to use it static.. put it in a separate static class and initiate it in a static constructor of that class.. so it will be initiated with the first call to the static class regardless of the caller..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the `Second` constructor, since `First.MyProperty` is initialized by `First` as soon as you access it, no matter whether through `Second` or "directly". However, as Daniel comments, you might consider using instances. Stateful statics are a smell too.

As an alternative, you may consider creation a `Factory` whose constructor takes a `MyObject`. This factory provides two methods for building `First` and `Second` instances, to which `MyObject` is passed. This does require you to pass around the instances instead of accessing the static classes, which I must admit is less convenient.

Comment: Yes you're right! That was too obvious to spot it the first time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

yes - there is a pattern, it's called Singleton

check the 5th solution here http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html

Comment: In .NET 4.0, people should just use a static Lazy<T>

Answer (score -1):

```
public static class First
{
    private Static MyObject _myproperty;
    static First() {}
    public static MyProperty
    {
        get 
        { 
             if(_myproperty == null) _myproperty = new MyObject();
             return _myproperty; 
        }
        set { _myproperty = value; }
    }
}

public static class Second
{
    static Second() {}
    public static MyProperty
    {
        get { return First.MyProperty; }
        set { First.MyProperty= value; }
    }
}
```

If you really want to do it this way. But... why not accessing First.Myproperty at first ? For me it just wrong to access via Second a property of First.

Comment: I'm not the -1 guy. I'd like to point out, however, that this implementation is not thread-safe. This may of course be fine. If late initialization is important, and `MyProperty` is not the first property to be accessed, `Interlocked` class helps exchanging `_myproperty`'s value in a thread-safe (and lock-free I guess) way, if needed.